# Select form doest show option preview

Tags: html, css, django, css-selectors

I found out that the css that I placed makes the preview to the option in the select forms disappear.
I can't seem to find a solution online on how to fix this.

This is the css part that causes the said issue:

```
.form-control{
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

As you can see below, when I remove this, the preview to the select option goes back.

With the css .form-control:

[image: with the css]

Without the css .form-control:

[image: without the css]

Here is "without the css" when I select an option:
[image: without the css]

I'm using django so this is how to placed the form in my html template:

```
{{ form | crispy }}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you post the associated HTML? Right now we have no way of knowing where the `.form-control` class acts.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've already updated my post

Comment: Yeah I don't know django so I can't help you, but now, others might!

Comment: I think it's because of padding you have set. remove `padding: 20px`

Comment: Oh right, that fixed it! Thanks! But what if I want the form to have some padding? Is there a way around that issue to make it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to not set `height` if you want `padding` or calculate content size and set padding.

```css
#cars {
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```